# Disable Safari on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, safari, permission

How do I disable access to Safari on macOS Ventura? I want to either change the permissions so that it can't be opened, hide it from appearing in Applications, or otherwise prevent access.

I have tried to change privileges for "everyone" in sharing and permissions to "No Access", which used to work in Monterey. However, after updating to Ventura, it now says that I do not have necessary permissions, even after disabling SIP.

I've tried to set app limits in screen time, but it only allows me to set a time limit instead of restricting access completely, and even then I could just turn screen time off.

Is there any way for me to prevent Safari from being opened or otherwise being used for browsing?

Answer (score 1):

In the Screen Time settings, set a "Screen Time Passcode." This is a 4-digit pin code you enter to lock Screen Time from being modified.

Then, in Screen Time > Content & Privacy (enable if disabled) > Content Restrictions, set "Access to Web Content" to "Allowed Websites Only."

Safari will still open, but will be unable to navigate to any webpages.

Comment: I've tried restricting web content to "Allowed Websites Only", and while it does work, it also interferes with web browsing on Chrome, which I do not want to disable completely. Is it possible to make the content restrictions apply only to Safari? As for setting a Screen Time password, it says I must revert my account from an admin to a regular user to do so.

Comment: @PeterNguyen You can override that, but keep in mind that an admin account can override any setting you set anywhere. It is ineffective to apply a restriction to an admin account, since they can override any restriction.

Comment: You could try your original approach, set a 1 minute limit to Safari. However that will still allow 1 minute of browsing in Safari.